# Symfony 1.4, I want a little modified url working (routing?) how?

Tags: php, url, symfony1

All links works as I expect but now I have to make a custom URL.
Let it be "userprofile/username"
where the `userprofile` is the module name, while `username` is not an action but the user name. A GET parameter, in other words. How to create a routing like that, and apply to this module only? Sadly I created a /config/routing.yml into that module, and not seems to be taken account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your routing.yml file is global for the application, you can't specify a different one for a specific module. This is because Symfony must find a matching route before it knows which module to use.

Try this in your *apps/appname/config/routing.yml* file:

```
user_profile:
  url:    /userprofile/:username
  param:  { module: userprofile, action: showUser }
```

Then in your *apps/appname/modules/userprofile/actions/actions.class.php* have an action like this:

```
public function executeShowUser(sfWebRequest $request) {
  $username = $request->getParameter('username');
  //do something!
}
```

And as always, don't forget to run *symfony cc* after changing any config file.

Comment: Try browsing your project in the browser using the dev environment to get more helpful error messages from symfony.
This is usually something like frontend_dev.php (or **appname**_dev.php) and then the rest of your url (e.g. localhost/frontend_dev.php/userprofile/zzzrByte
My guess is that you will get an error that showUserSuccess.php doesn't exist.  Create it in apps/appname/modules/userprofile/templates/showUserSuccess.php

Comment: it does exists, but if I modify "url:    /userprofile/:username.html" and call it "/userprofile/name.html" it works good. But I dont want that .html

Comment: If /userprofile/name.html correctly translates to the route /userprofile/:username.html ... But /userprofile/name doesn't translate to the route /userprofile/:username than it may be possible you have a problem with your server configuration. Are you getting a Symfony error? Have you tried using frontend_dev.php to see more detailed errors?

Comment: Is it possible you have a default routing rule above this one? Try placing the routing rule for user_profile at the top of your routing.yml and then running symfony cc again. If this doesn't work, show me your routing.yml file.

Comment: well, yes replacing it that module works.... but everything else went down xD (Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/config" (/).) now the config file contain your suggestion only

Comment: Are the rest of your routes relying on the default Symfony routing rules? It's pretty bad practice in my opinion to fallback to /:module/:action for all your rules... It's better to define each rule explicitly, as it would give you a lot more flexibility, and you would be missing out on the entire point of the routing system.

Comment: You should really read the documentation: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System#chapter_09_what_is_routing - as I'm reading those comments, you have no idea how the SF1 routing works. zzzrByte answer is the right one by the way.

Comment: yes. The new rule simply had to be put before the symfony's default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

so, to be a valuable topic:

```
# You can find more information about this file on the symfony website:
# http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/10-Routing

user_profile:
  url:    /userprofile/:username
  param:  { module: userprofile, action: showUser }

# default rules
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: index, action: index }

# generic rules
# please, remove them by adding more specific rules


default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```